# VBA code change while running

Tags: vba, excel

I have a vba with declaration of some constant, such as

```
Public Const prev = ""
```

My idea is that the VBA code will update/change this constant prev everytime the code was run.
In the past, I have found out the solution of this case, but unfortunately I forgot to save it . So I sure that we can do it with VBA. But now I cannot find it again.

Comment: Why declare something as a `constant` if you want to change it?

Comment: Cause I use Workbook event handler to trigger my vba code. And the constant will store the result from last run and pass it to vba code when trigger were turn on

Comment: You can not change the value of a constant at run-time. Declare a normal variable instead; `Public prev as String`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change values, declare it as

```
public prev as {your data type}
```

constants are **immutable** once the compiler reserves the memory for it you won't have a change to modify it again unless you are recompiling.

Comment: Cause I use Workbook event handler to trigger my vba code. And the constant will store the result from last run and pass it to vba code when trigger were turned on

Comment: then, save the variables in a worksheet or file or registry.

Answer (score 0):

finnally I have found out the way

```
Application.VBE.CodePanes(1).CodeModule.ReplaceLine 1, "Public Const prev = " & strValue
```

For those who vote down my question, if you dont have enough knowledge , just dont think that it cannot work

Comment: I think your question was downvoted because you tried to achieve your goal in a very complicated way. Writing the value to a cell or a file would be easier, and doesn't conflict any changes of your code structure.

Comment: I know that will be easier but the requirement is that. I am not the one who use this code.